# Where do I ask Google Apps & iGoogle related Question?

Tags: support, questions, answers

Hello everyone,

I have been working with Google Apps & iGoogle Gadget & just used to ask some queries like [postini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632683/what-is-postini-server), [iGoogle Gadget Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632669/can-i-write-the-igoogle-gadget-data-back-to-google-spreadsheet-using-javascript), [Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568593/how-to-fetch-gmail-subject-header-from-part-of-any-mail), [RSS Feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569360/rss-feed-shows-only-unread-mails), [Gmail Gadget for Personal Gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546822/mail-gadget-for-personal-domain-on-personal-website). But I haven't found proper solution for them still ! Am I on the correct place to ask these questions. Or where do I need to shift for such questions ?

Answer (score 5):

If you're programming something and need help with the code: **[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)**

If you're an end user and need help making the damn thing work for your account or needs (but aren't writing any lines of code): **[webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)**